# CKEDITOR: get data from multiple instance names in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Because I have multiple textareas in HTML code, I pass the id value through Javascript to retrieve the data in each textareas. However, in the JS function, the "CKEDITOR.instances.id" doesn't represent as expected such as CKEDITOR.instances.editor_1, CKEDITOR.instances.editor_2, or CKEDITOR.instances.editor_4, therefore, I don't have any data retrieved. Anyone knows how to fix this please let me. Heaps of thanks.

HTML code:

```
    <textarea name="edit_1"></textarea>
    <input type="button" value="submit" onClick="getValue('edit_1')" />
    <textarea name="edit_2"></textarea>
    <input type="button" value="submit" onClick="getValue('edit_2')" />
    <textarea name="edit_2"></textarea>
    <input type="button" value="submit" onClick="getValue('edit_3')" />
```

JS code:

```
    var getValue = function(id) {
        var content = CKEDITOR.instances.id.getData();
        alert(content);
    };
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding [] between id

```
var getValue = function(id) {
    var content = CKEDITOR.instances[id].getData();
    alert(content);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

i had to do something like this as i was binding events to actions with multiple instances.
and trying to get the data but it would always return null for any one but the last... using the event (e.editor) worked though.

```
var editors = CKEDITOR.instances;
    for (var x in editors) {
      if (editors[x]) {
        var thisName = editors[x].name;
        if (editors[thisName]) {
          editors[thisName].on('focus', function (e) {
            socket.emit('ckeditor_field_type_edit', user, e.editor.name);
          });
          editors[thisName].on('key', function (e) {
            var data = e.editor.getData();
            socket.emit('ckeditor_field_type_typing', user, e.editor.name, data);
          });
          editors[thisName].on('blur', function (e) {
            var data = e.editor.getData();
            setTimeout(function () {
              socket.emit('ckeditor_field_type_edit_finish', user, e.editor.name, data);
            }, 1000);
          });
        }
      }
    }
```